# Replace links with some other link in a text

Tags: javascript, regex

I have below description, which I am trying to replace the links in `href` props with signed s3 links ***on the backend without DOM***

So, I need to first loop over all the matching s3 links and replace it with signed one.

The problem is It replaces other parts as well. It doesn't know when to end the matching.

Here is what I am trying to do,

1. Collect all the links
2. Filter links which has s3 related keyword
3. replace them with signed s3 link

```js
function replaceNonSignedS3WithSignedLink(text) {
  const urlRegex = /(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g;
  return text.replace(urlRegex, function(url) {
    return 'https://signed-s3-link.com';
  })
  // or alternatively
  // return text.replace(urlRegex, '<a href="$1">$1</a>')
}
const desc = `<h3>Introduction Session</h3><p>Monday, March 3, 2021 11:00AM - 01:00PM</p> 
    Click <a href='https://example.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/bio.pdf'>here</a>`;

const result = replaceNonSignedS3WithSignedLink(desc);

console.log(result)
```

The result I get is,

```
"<h3>Introduction Session</h3><p>Monday, March 3, 2021 11:00AM - 01:00PM</p> 
    Click <a href='https://signed-s3-link.com"
```

Comment: Regex processing of HTML is a [bad approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3136474). Couldn't you replace the links in the DOM by selecting `a` tags instead of replacing them using regex in the HTML code?

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong with the link matching regex, this seems to work for my case.

```js
let i = 0;
function urlify(text) {
  var urlRegex = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
  return text.replace(urlRegex, function(url) {
    if (url.includes('s3')) return 'https://signed-s3-link.com' + ++i; // I can process individual link here
    return url;
  })
}

var text = `<h3>Introduction Session</h3><p>Monday, March 3, 2021 11:00AM - 01:00PM</p> 
    Click <a href='https://example.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/bio.pdf'>here</a> <a href = 'https://hello.com'>Hi</a>`;
var html = urlify(text);

console.log(html)
```

Comment: I thought you only wanted to change links that contained s3?

Comment: That can be easily achieve with `if (url.includes('s3')){ // update the link}`

Comment: I know. Like I did in my answer.

Comment: @mplungjan The limitation is, which I forgot to mention,  It is being processing on backend. So, there is no DOM to access.

Comment: So it is a straight dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/how-to-replace-plain-urls-with-links

Comment: @mplungjan It seems I can also use this package. https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom#readme